# SSD - Disk is OK, one bad sector

Tags: laptop, ssd, bad-sectors

The make is **Crucial MX500 2.5-INCH SSD 250GB**, I bought it a half year ago and so far it works flawlessly, fine quality piece of hardware I must say.

My laptop is w/o battery and I guess sometimes I might just unplug the machine from the power network (w/o properly shutting it down, even though it takes 1 second..) and move it somewhere else.

OS - **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS**, I saw the above message (see title) and was wondering why is that?

**On the next start of disks utility the message was gone**, I read that it means that the sector was "re-allocated" or something?

Is there something wrong with the disk, is it because I am not paying too much attention on how I am using it and stuff?

P.S. How many sectors are there anyway, and is this something that would affect system performance or anything else?

Comment: @Ramhound, ah I see.. so "hard boot/ cold boot" is also bad, not just "cold reboot" (unplugging the power cord w/o OS shut down first)? *If my understanding is correct.

Comment: "sometimes I might just unplug the machine from the power network (w/o properly shutting it down" smh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One bad block (or sector in hard drives), doesn't mean too much.  Any drive can get an occasional random failure in a location.  When it happens, the drive controller tries to relocate the contents to another block (or sector).  It will spend some time retrying it and moving content.  That will momentarily affect performance, but you may not notice it because it will be similar to the drive just being busy.

Eventually, the drive will run out of spares and become unusable.  The issue isn't so much the number of bad blocks in relation to the total number of blocks, it's the number in relation to the number of spares.  SSDs are "over-provisioned" with more blocks than the advertised capacity.
This improves performance and provides spares for expected failure rates over the planned life of the drive.

The problem is when there is a recurring pattern with new bad blocks.  That indicates the drive is in the process of dying, and you should use the available time to ensure you have current backups and prepare to replace it.  Get your files onto something else while you still can.

With a HDD, a recurring pattern of new bad sectors indicates that the drive platters are physically deteriorating.  With SSDs, the memory cells have a finite number of storage cycles, and wear leveling is employed to even out usage across the entire drive.  So when memory cells start to fail, all of the memory cells are in a similar condition.  A recurring pattern of new bad blocks means that the SSD is at the end of its life.

So seeing that message is good from the perspective that something is keeping track of it and alerting you; you will be aware of a problem if you start seeing the message on more than very rare occasions.

Ramhound's comment about hard shutdown is a different issue.  If you just pull the plug instead of shutting down gracefully, the drive may be left with corruption because write operations may not have been completed.  That won't be physical damage, but you're likely to get a message either that a bad sector was detected or that there could potentially be a problem.

The operating system is aware of when the system was not shut down properly and knows to check the drive for corruption just in case there was any.  Depending on the nature of the corruption, you might have a file that can't be recovered, or even a system problem if a critical file was left unusable.

Even though you aren't likely to cause physical damage with a hard shutdown, it will cause problems that are a pain in the butt.  Best case, you will have a very long boot time while it checks for potential corruption.  Worst case, you will lose files or need to spend time recovering system files to get operational again.  So don't just pull the plug.

Comment: I see, I guess I will keep an eye on it then and see if there will be more such messages in future, I have not noticed anything in terms of performance or others. To answer your question, the application which reported it is - "gnome-disk-utility gnome disks". About: Using Disks, you can view SMART data, manage devices, benchmark physical disks, and image USB sticks.

Comment: Thanks, fixer1234 for the detailed answer and for the additional clarifications around hard shutdown and the nature of my error message. I will do as suggested by you and Ramhound - will stop unplugging the cord w/o properly restarting first, keep and eye on my disks utility and use the laptop/SSD normally.

Comment: Worth bearing in mind that, if the drive can't read the contents of the bad sector after however many attempts it is willing to try for, a lot of the time it will relocate the sector but discard the data (i.e. fill it with zeros). So it will appear that the drive has resolved the issue and is now operating normally but a file could potentially be corrupted.

Comment: Also with SSDs the distinction between "normal" and "spare" sectors isn't so clear-cut. With SSDs we talk about "overprovisioning" i.e. making the flash media with more sectors than the drive claims to have as its capacity. However, unlike a mechanical hard drive, all of the sectors are used equally as part of the "wear leveling" process. In other words, the drive is constantly moving data around between sectors, even if none have failed. When a sector fails, it doesn't take a brand-new unused "reserved" sector to replace it; it simply makes a note to stop using the failed sector.

Comment: Would running some variation of `fsck` do any good on an SSD? It works nicely on spinning rust.

Comment: @Joe, sure. Take a look at [How to check SSD disk for errors from a Live CD?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/158424/85417).

Answer (score 5):

SSDs wear out in a very different manner than do electromechanical hard drives.

With hard drives, sector reallocation typically becomes necessary because a piece of the underlying physical media (a tiny portion of a platter) has started to fail. This can gradually spread from the faulty part of the platter, resulting in a rapid accumulation of reallocated sectors. In many cases, this will escalate to actual data corruption and eventual drive failure. As a result, even one reallocated sector on a hard drive is justification for replacing the drive.

SSDs generally store data in arrays of NAND flash memory cells that are grouped into pages and blocks. While the drive's controller will try to [spread out writes to prevent premature failure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wear_leveling), over extended usage, some blocks will still fail before others. NAND wear is localized to the underlying memory cells on the silicon and doesn't "spread"—the drive will simply rewrite the data in the failing block onto a spare block. This is part of how SSDs manage wear on the NAND, so reallocated blocks generally don't indicate imminent failure unless the value is increasing rapidly with use. Indeed, due to the imperfections inherent to semiconductor manufacturing, most NAND flash memory chips have some number of bad blocks from the factory, which either quickly fail early in the drive's life and are reallocated without incident, or are simply never used by the drive. Instead, it is better to monitor the amount of *spare blocks* remaining, and replace the drive if the drive is running low on spare blocks.

You most likely have nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 3):

Beyond theory, the best answer to your question, “Is there something wrong with the disk,” is we can’t tell you.

However, the best way to find out is to use the manufacturer provided tool called [Storage Executive](https://www.crucial.com/usa/en/support-storage-executive) to find out the status and health of your drive. Additionally, you can perform maintenance tasks such as upgrading the firmware.

Unfortunately, this appears to only be available on Windows.

Comment: Yep, a lot of things are Windows only ignoring the fact that more and more developer and not only configurations are using Linux distributions, I'll keep an eye for other bad stuff errors and discontinue the practice of unplugging the cord while ON. Thanks for the link though, good to know that there is any.. I couldn't find it earlier with google.

Comment: There are plenty of utilities for reading SMART data in Linux.